# How to align text within an algorithm environment?

Tags: spacing, algorithms, algorithm2e

I wish to duplicate an effect I've seen elsewhere (image below) in which text not necessarily at the beginning of a line is aligned with text elsewhere.

[image: aligned algorithm example]

I don't know which environment is suitable, but I assume one of the various algorithm environments fits the bill (w.r.t. structure). I have tried with the apparently popular `algorithm2e` package, but could not see a way to do it.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Algorithm}
    Let  \quad $ X $ be the set of $ n $ training patterns $ x_{1}, x_{2}, \dots x_{n} $\;
     \qquad $ W $ be a $ p \times q $ grid of units $ w_{ij} $ where $ i $ and $ j $ are their coordinates on that grid\;
    \qquad $ \alpha $ be the learning rate, assuming values in $ [0,1] $, initialized to a given initial learning rate\;
    \qquad $ r $ be the radius of the neighborhood function $ h(w_{ij},w_{mn},r $), initialized to a given initial radius\;
   \Repeat{$ \alpha $ reaches 0}{
     \For{$ k=1 $ to $  n $}{
       For all $ w_{ij} \in W $, calculate $ d_{ij} = || x_{k} - w_{ij} || $\;
       Select the unit that minimizes $d_{ij}$ as the winner $ w_{winner} $\;
       Update each unit $ w_{ij} \in W: w_{ij} = w_{ij} +  \alpha  h(w_{winner}, w_{ij}, r) || x_{k} - w_{ij} || $\;
     Decrease the value of $ \alpha $ and $ r $
    }
   }
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

which produces...

[image]

This shows two problems: 1) the alignment doesn't exist, and 2) when a line wraps, it doesn't have an indent. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here `tabularx` package is proposed to achieve the 2 objectives. Three columns are assigned with different property `{l>{$}c<{$}X}`. Further, `.xx\textwidth` can be changed via decimal number .xx.

[image]

Codes

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Algorithm}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l>{$}c<{$}X}
Let &     X  & be the set of $ n $ training patterns $ x_{1}, x_{2}, \dots x_{n} $\\
    & W  &be a $ p \times q $ grid of units $ w_{ij} $ where $ i $ and $ j $ are their coordinates on that grid\\
    &  \alpha  & be the learning rate, assuming values in $ [0,1] $, initialized to a given initial learning rate\\
      &  r  & be the radius of the neighborhood function $ h(w_{ij},w_{mn},r )$, initialized to a given initial radius
\end{tabularx}
   \Repeat{$ \alpha $ reaches 0}{
     \For{$ k=1 $ to $  n $}{
       For all $ w_{ij} \in W $, calculate $ d_{ij} = || x_{k} - w_{ij} || $\;
       Select the unit that minimizes $d_{ij}$ as the winner $ w_{winner} $\;
       Update each unit $ w_{ij} \in W: w_{ij} = w_{ij} +  \alpha  h(w_{winner}, w_{ij}, r) || x_{k} - w_{ij} || $\;
     Decrease the value of $ \alpha $ and $ r $
    }
   }
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh the shame, I assumed other environments couldn't be used inside algorithm. I had tried the `align` environment and it didn't like it.

Comment: Ya, I had that experiences too. But it is the X column specifier leads me to use tabularx; X is like a p column, except that the width is calculated automatically.

Comment: Thanks! I now have the problem that the table is included in the numbering of lines (when that option is set in the preamble). Any idea how to manage that? I'm trying some things but they are not working.

Comment: I took a quick review of the manual of algorithm2e (from googling). There are two examples on page 5 and 10 may provide some help.

Comment: Gah! I tried, and gave up. The docs are just too difficult to interpret.

Comment: Yes, I know the feeling. I did try and run the cases on my pc, but no numbering showed up. If by chance i know how someday, will leave a comment to you.

Comment: I found a way, and perhaps I should add it as an answer as it's a little too long for here. Essentially I used the `\SetKwInput` command to create a new `input` "verb", and had it print "Let". That then allowed me to wrap the tabular inside it and avoid that entire section being numbered (as the `input` section is not a numbered section). I also tried the same with the `data` section using `\SetKwData`--it had similar but not optimal results.

Comment: Yes, you can post an answer yourself, saying how to add numbering to the OP (kind of a follow-up). I would love to see it.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Jesse I have a means to obtain a pretty nice representation, with line numbering of part of the algorithm. It looks like this:

[image]

The tabular is wrapped inside the `input` keyword (redefined as "Let" using `\SetKwInput`---see page 34 of the v5.0 manual, section 11). The Input, Output, and Data sections in algorithm2e are not numbered. It does set the word "Let" to be centred vertically beside the tabular, but I can't be spending my entire day trying to fix a tiny little thing like that now can I?

Code:

```
\LinesNumbered
\SetKwInput{KwLet}{Let}
\begin{algorithm}[htbp]
\KwLet{ \begin{tabularx}{0.8\textwidth}{>{$}c<{$} X}
     X  & be the set of $ n $ training vectors $ x_{1}, x_{2}, \dots x_{n} $\\
     W  &be a $ p \times q $ grid of units $ w_{ij} $ where $ i $ and $ j $ are their coordinates on that grid\\
      \alpha  & be the learning rate, assuming values in $ [0,1] $, initialised to a given initial learning rate\\
        r  & be the radius of the neighbourhood function $ h(w_{ij},w_{mn},r )$, initialised to a given initial radius
\end{tabularx}}
\BlankLine
   \Repeat{$ \alpha $ reaches 0}{
     \For{ k=1  to n }{
       For all $ w_{ij} \in W $, calculate $ d_{ij} = || x_{k} - w_{ij} || $\;
       Select the unit that minimizes $d_{ij}$ as the winner $ w_{winner} $\;
       Update each unit $ w_{ij} \in W: \allowbreak w_{ij} = w_{ij} +  \alpha  h(w_{winner}, w_{ij}, r) || x_{k} - w_{ij} || $\;
     Decrease the value of $ \alpha $ and $ r $
    }
   }
\caption{Algorithm}
\end{algorithm}
```

Comment: Have just realised that if I change the width of the tabular using something like `0.6\textwidth` then the "Let" keyword is set beside the tabular. However it's centred vertically, so not sure whether I like that or the version posted above.

Comment: Updated the code and figure.

Comment: add a '\newline' command at the begining of wapping. i.e., '\KwLet{\newline ... ' can move the Let up on top, if that is what you wish to have.