# Align the word input of algorithm2e with a tabularx table

Tags: vertical-alignment, tabularx, algorithm2e

I'm referring to this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/144320/45570). I like the idea from 'a different ben' of the tabularx table inside the `\Input` command. But I would like to have the word `Input:` at the top, on the same line as the first row of the table. The suggested `\newline` in the linked post doesn't work for me.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[ruled,longend,german,algochapter]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}
  \begin{algorithm}[tbp]
    \SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}
    \SetKwInOut{Output}{Output}
    \LinesNumbered
    \caption[Description]{Description}
\Input{\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{.03\textwidth}p{.03\textwidth}X}
                    $a$ &   -- &    Desc1   \\
                    $b$ &   -- &    Desc2   \\
                    $c$ &   -- &    Desc3   
        \end{tabularx}
      }
  \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `[t]` for setting the vertical alignment; however, your tabular will be too wide.

```
\documentclass[draft]{scrbook}

\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry} % just to show the margins

\usepackage{tabularx,calc}
\usepackage[ruled,longend,german,algochapter]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{algotabularx}
 {\tabularx{\linewidth-\inoutsize-\widthof{~~~}-4\tabcolsep-\rightskip}[t]}
 {\endtabularx}


\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[tbp]
\SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}
\SetKwInOut{Output}{Output}
\LinesNumbered
\caption[Description]{Description}
\Input{Something to show the alignment}
\Input{%
  \begin{algotabularx}{@{}p{.03\textwidth}p{.03\textwidth}X@{}}
  $a$ &   -- &    \lipsum*[2]  \\
  $b$ &   -- &    Desc2   \\
  $c$ &   -- &    Desc3   
  \end{algotabularx}%
}
\Output{Something else}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, I didn't notice that the text will go over the right side, it was too short in my example.

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[ruled,longend,german,algochapter]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}
  \begin{algorithm}[tbp]
    \SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}
    \SetKwInOut{Output}{Output}
    \LinesNumbered
    \caption[Description]{Description}
\Input{\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}[t]{p{.03\textwidth}p{.03\textwidth}X}
                                   %%%
                                   %%%
                                   %%%
                    $a$ &   -- &    Desc1   \\
                    $b$ &   -- &    Desc2   \\
                    $c$ &   -- &    Desc3   
        \end{tabularx}
      }
  \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks :), I tried `\begin{tabularx}[t]{\textwidth}{p{.03\textwidth}p{.03\textwidth}X}` but that gave me dozen of errors. I didn't realize that the `[t]` needs to be after the second curly braces pair.

Comment: This does cause an overfull `\hbox` though...

Comment: @Werner yes I just answered the question, not the next one:-)